# How to jump into a method from switch statement in c#?

Tags: c#

how to jump to a method from the switch-case statement?

for example:

in the switch statement there is a case, and if it is that case matched, you will jump to a method that given at the codeblock of a case. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just call this method

Comment: `case x: jump()`

Comment: of course you can do that.. simply call the method inside the case.

Comment: Here is a little [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wXnNl8)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question right, but a switch statement will execute everything below the case that matches. Example:

```
switch (myIntVar)
{
case 1:
//Code for when myIntVar equals 1
break;

case 2:
//Code for when myIntVar equals 2
break;

default:
//Code for when myIntVar has any other value
break;
}
```

Note that the `break` at the end of each case prevents the execution of other case's code. Without it, when `myIntVar` equals 1, the code from `case 1`, `case 2` and `default` would be ran in this example.

So if you want to call a specific method for each case statement, you should just include it like this:

```
switch (myIntVar)
{
case 1:
myMethod1();
break;

case 2:
myMethod2();
break;

default:
myMethodDefault();
break;
}
```

Comment: Except that in C# it is illegal to fall through to a following case